# How to do multiple selection and insert them into database

Tags: laravel

I would like to make a multiple selection through the combobox and insert them into the database. the idea is to make an array and then make his appeal.
with what I've made, a single choice adds to the base. Would anyone have any idea how to insert all zones selected into my database.Thanks

**Model 1**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class zoneintervention extends Model
{
public function techniciens()
{
    return $this-
```

> belongsToMany('App\technicien','technicien_zone','zoneintervention_id','technicien_id');

```
}
}
```

**Model 2**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class technicien extends Model
{

     public function zoneintervention()
{
    return $this-
```

> belongsToMany('App\zoneintervention','technicien_zone','technicien_id','z
>       oneintervention_id');

```
}

public function tarificationtache()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tarificationtache::class);
}

}
```

**Controler**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\technicien;
use App\zoneintervention;

class TechnicienController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $Listzone=zoneintervention::orderBy('code_postal')->get();
    $Listtechnicien=technicien::all();


    return view('technicien.index',['technicien'=>$Listtechnicien]);   

}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{

    $zoneintervention = Zoneintervention::orderBy('id', 'desc')-
 >get();
    return view('technicien.create')->with('zoneintervention', 
 $zoneintervention);

}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $technicien = new technicien();
    $technicien ->actif =$request->input('actif');
    $technicien ->moyenne_avis =$request->input('moyenne_avis');
    $technicien = new technicien();
    $technicien->actif = $request->input('actif');
    $technicien->moyenne_avis = $request->input('moyenne_avis');
    $technicien->save();

    $technicien->zoneintervention()->attach($request-
    >zoneintervention_id);

    return redirect('technicien');



}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

**create**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@section('content')
@if(count($errors))
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
 <ul>
    @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
     <li>{{$message}}</li>
        @endforeach
 </ul>
</div>
@endif
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action=" {{url ('technicien')  }}" method="post">
         {{csrf_field()}}


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="zoneintervention">zoneintervention</label>


                <select multiple name="zoneintervention_id" 
id="zoneintervention" class="form-control" >

                        @foreach($zoneintervention as 
$zoneintervention)
                         <option value="{{ $zoneintervention->id }}">
                            {{$zoneintervention->code_postal}}
                         </option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>


             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Moyenne Avis</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="moyenne_avis" class="form-
control"value="{{old('moyenne_avis')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Etat</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="actif" class="form-
control"value="{{old('actif')}}">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" 
class="form-control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your blade file you can do:

```
...
<select multiple name="zoneintervention_id[]" id="zoneintervention" class="form-control" >
...
```

In your controller,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //This will give you an array of all the selected item
    dd($request['zoneintervention_id']);
}
```